# Why is 'to' correct in this case?

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

I'm preparing for a TOEIC test, and today I faced with a reading question below:

> John's Online Board will not accept any posting that are
>   discriminatory or misleading ...... its members.
>
> A. by
>
> B. to
>
> C. upon
>
> D. with

The answer is (B). Why can't we choose 'with' (D) for this case?

Comment: i think, act of "discrimination" is against someone, not together. why did you think, it should be 'with'?

Comment: You usually use the preposition 'to' after the adjective showing a bad effect on somebody.

Comment: Just a small aside, have you copied it slightly wrong? Should it have been "posting**s**"?

Comment: @JamesWebster: Thank James, that was my typo mistake. It is "postings" , not "posting".

Comment: I would like to add that I would use the secret hidden option e) towards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (B) and not (D) because discrimination or being misled are things that happen **to** people, as opposed to things that happen **with** people.

This is because they are actions committed by somebody else, the subject, having an effect on the object (John's Online Board members, in this case).